# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

So while writing and testing the trial code(Java) of twilio for sending the SMS iam getting the above error. here is the code below:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class Sms {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACb519b651243a021f900be0b0d387edc9";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "I_CAN'T_SHARE";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+19916022xxx"),
                new PhoneNumber("+18082010XXX"),
                "Sent from a Twilio Trial Account").create(); // the number in the from phone number field is provided by twilio

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }

}
```

exception stack trace:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.ConfigOverrides.<init>(ConfigOverrides.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:480)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:31)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:6)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:104)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:122)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at sms.Sms.main(Sms.java:17)
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. This is probably conflict in dependencies. If you are using maven, please edit your post to add pom.xml

Comment: No buddy it's not a maven project...
I created this as a Java project....

Comment: Still i think this is dependency issue. Could you post list of dependencies and its versions imported in CLASSPATH?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a dependency issue.

Comment: I too agree with you @Bedla. It's sure that I am adding wrong versions of Jar files in classpath. So can please list the Jar files and their versions which I have to add in the classpath except Twilio Jar. or any resource where I can find this info because it's not mentioned in Twilio guid that what are external Jars I have to add....

Comment: same question for you @philnash. As you are a Twilio dev. can you please tell why they haven't mentioned the other Jars to keep in the classpath for developing a Twilio java app..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Java library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) is usable without maven you just have to ensure you have the correct dependencies. The documentation lists [two ways of using the jar without a build tool](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java#using-without-a-build-automation-tool).

[You can either download a jar with the dependencies included, called twilio-7.x.x-with-dependencies.jar, from the maven repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twilio/sdk/twilio/7.15.6/).

Or, you can get it without dependencies by [downloading twilio-7.x.x.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twilio/sdk/twilio/7.15.6/) and getting [the dependencies which are listed in the projects pom.xml file](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/pom.xml).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the resources Phil...
Let me try this and will let know the result

Comment: Thanks, the code is working fine and properly but the problem is I am not receiving the message on my phone. I am sending a text message from Twilio provided phone number(+1) to my Indian number(+91). can you tell me why...???

Comment: There's a number of reasons you might not receive this message. First, are you using your real credentials (not the test credentials)? Also, check this list of [troubleshooting for sending to Indian numbers](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices).